# oracle - merge multiple column values

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have following data set:

DAILY_DATA:

| DEPT | CLASS | DATE | BOOK_ID | TRANSFER_RETAIL | TRANSFER_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 10-APR | 100 | 23.4 | 54 |
| 100 | 1 | 10-APR | 200 | 0 | 92 |

I want to merge the values of TRANSFER_RETAIL AND TRANSFER_COST
and add it to the row where BOOK_ID = 100

so the row will show:

| DEPT | CLASS | DATE | BOOK_ID | TRANSFER_RETAIL | TRANSFER_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 10-APR | 100 | 23.4 | 146 |
| 100 | 1 | 10-APR | 200 | 0 | 92 |

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` statement to combine the rows:

```sql
MERGE INTO daily_data dst
USING (
  SELECT dept,
         class,
         "DATE",
         SUM(transfer_retail) AS transfer_retail,
         SUM(transfer_cost) AS transfer_cost
  FROM   daily_data
  WHERE  book_id = 200
  -- AND dept = 100
  -- AND class = 1
  -- AND "DATE" = DATE '2022-04-10'
  GROUP BY dept, class, "DATE"
) src
ON (    dst.book_id = 100
    AND dst.dept    = src.dept
    AND dst.class   = src.class
    AND dst."DATE"  = src."DATE")
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET transfer_retail = dst.transfer_retail + src.transfer_retail,
      transfer_cost   = dst.transfer_cost + src.transfer_cost;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DAILY_DATA (DEPT, CLASS, "DATE", BOOK_ID, TRANSFER_RETAIL, TRANSFER_COST) AS
SELECT 100, 1, DATE '2022-04-10', 100, 23.4, 54 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 1, DATE '2022-04-10', 200, 0,    92 FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE`, the table will contain:

> | DEPT | CLASS | DATE | BOOK_ID | TRANSFER_RETAIL | TRANSFER_COST |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | 1 | 10-APR-22 | 100 | 23.4 | 146 |
> | 100 | 1 | 10-APR-22 | 200 | 0 | 92 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a44aeb4593aedec80608e2244df42401)*

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that it would be better to create a VIEW than to modify the raw data. This avoids all risk that the update query is run twice etc. and the original data is always avaliable.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DAILY_DATA(DEPT INT,CLASS int, "DATE" DATE,BOOK_ID INT, TRANSFER_RETAIL DECIMAL(5,2),TRANSFER_COST DECIMAL(5,2));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO DAILY_DATA 
> SELECT 100, 1,to_date('2022-04-10','yyyy-mm-dd'),100,23.4,54 FROM dual UNION ALL
> SELECT 100, 1,to_date('2022-04-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), 200, 0, 92 FROM dual
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW TOTALLED AS
> SELECT
>   DEPT,
>   CLASS,
>   "DATE",
>   BOOK_ID,
>     CASE WHEN BOOK_ID = 100 THEN SUM(TRANSFER_RETAIL) OVER(partition BY "DATE")
>       ELSE TRANSFER_RETAIL end TRANSFER_RETAIL,
>     CASE WHEN BOOK_ID = 100 THEN SUM(TRANSFER_COST) OVER(partition BY "DATE") 
>       ELSE TRANSFER_COST end TRANSFER_COST
> from DAILY_DATA;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM TOTALLED;
> ```
>
> ```
> DEPT | CLASS | DATE      | BOOK_ID | TRANSFER_RETAIL | TRANSFER_COST
> ---: | ----: | :-------- | ------: | --------------: | ------------:
>  100 |     1 | 10-APR-22 |     200 |               0 |            92
>  100 |     1 | 10-APR-22 |     100 |            23.4 |           146
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=431ece6690806eeb9c56fcfdb512eed4)*

Answer (score 1):

Rather than merging them in an already existing column, just add a new virtual column
such as

```sql
ALTER TABLE daily_data
ADD (
      transfer_total AS ( transfer_retail+transfer_cost )
    );
```

which won't occupy any extra space within the data segment, and just used to display the desired computed value always depending on those two columns. Btw, your current column's value of `transfer_cost` will be kept as orginal, and the normalisation rule for the table will be protected.